# Advanced Movie filter problem with react and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing movie a movie site something like here https://www.justwatch.com/us?genres=scf&rating_imdb=5.1

"All, Movies, TV Shows" is a the main panel and genres option is a secondary panel and each time I click either All, Movies or Tv Shows it fetches data like it supposed to and then genre filter works on top of that also.

But the problem is when lets say I select "Romance" while main panel is selected on "Movies" and then I click "TV Shows" to replace "Movies" it fetches everything again and doesn't categorize Romance TV shows, it just shows all TV Shows and then i have click on "Romance" genre again:

i'm maping genre data from here:

```
const genreList = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name:'All',
    active: true,
    },

    {
    id: 2,
    name:'Thriller',
    active: false,
    },

    {
    id: 3,
    name:'Romance',
    active: false,
    },

    {
    id: 4,
    name:'Comedy',
    active: false,
    },

    {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Drama',
    active: false,
    },
]
```

pulling data from firestore:

```
const NavigateMovies = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
    const [genres, setGenres] = useState(genreList)
    const [videoType, setVideoType] = useState("All")

    async function fetchDataFromFirestore() {
        const data = []
        switch (videoType) {
            case "All":
                const querySnapshot1 = await getDocs(db.collection("movies"))
                const querySnapshot2 = await getDocs(db.collection("tvshows"))
                querySnapshot1.forEach((doc) => {
                data.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})
                })
                querySnapshot2.forEach((doc) => {
                data.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})
                })
                break;
                
            case "Movies":
                const querySnapshot3 = await getDocs(db.collection("movies"))
                querySnapshot3.forEach((doc) => {
                data.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})
                })
                break;

            case "Tv Shows":
                const querySnapshot4 = await getDocs(db.collection("tvshows"))
                querySnapshot4.forEach((doc) => {
                data.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})
                })
                break;
        }
        return data       
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const data = await fetchDataFromFirestore()
            setData(data)
            }
        fetchData()
    },[videoType])

    useEffect(() => {
        setMovies(data);
    }, [data])
```

then i'm doing this:

```
const handleFilterMovies = category => {
        setGenres(
        genres.map(genre => {
        genre.active = false;
        if(genre.name === category){
            genre.active = true;
        }
        return genre;
        })
        )

        if (category ==='All') {
            setMovies(data)
            return;
        }

        const filteredMovies = data.filter(movie => movie.genre === category)
        setMovies(filteredMovies)
    };
    
    return (
    <div className="movie-nav-container">
        <div className="categories">
            <button onClick={() => {setVideoType("All"); }}>All</button>
            <button onClick={() => {setVideoType("Movies"); }}>Movies</button>
            <button onClick={() => {setVideoType("Tv Shows"); }}>TV Shows</button>
            <ul>
                {
                    
                genres.map(genre => (
                    <li key={genre.id} className={`${genre.active ? 'active': undefined}`} onClick={()=>{handleFilterMovies(genre.name)}}>{genre.name}</li>
                ))
                }
            </ul>
        </div> 
        <div className="movies">
            {
            movies && movies.length >0 && movies.map(movie => (
            <div className='wrap'><img src={movie.imageCoverLink} alt="" /></div>
            ))
            }
        </div> 
    </div>)
}
```

I've tried all the combinations but it didn't seem to work

Comment: Instead of `setMovies(filteredMovies)`, have you tried `setMovies(loadedMoviesArr => loadedMoviesArr.filter(movie => movie.genre === category))` to make sure you are using the latest `data` array and not a stale copy?